# Best way to pass value into backing bean in Richfaces

Tags: richfaces

I have a table and use actionListener to perform delete action see following image.
right now i am using event.getComponets() to get value that set from f:param tag. however, in this way, i have to hard code component id in to backing bean. looks like not a good approach. it there a better way to passing value from UI when there is a list of action buttons in table.

> ```
>     final UIParameter parm = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent(EDIT_SITE_ID_PARM);
>     return (Integer)parm.getValue();
> ```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a4j:actionParam name=".." value="..", it works just like f:param but will also do the assignment to bean property automatically. Another option is to use f:setPropertyActionListener.

Comment: this looks like the answer i am looking for but i can't see the complete sentence.

Comment: Sorry, something happened to my answer. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your action listener should be like this:

```
public void deleteActionListener(ActionEvent event) {
        final String param = (String) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap().get("deleteIdParam");
                //convert to int and call your delete method
}
```

so you only hardcode the parameter's name ant not the component's id.

Of course, now your actionListener will be deleteActionListener instead of your old one.

Answer (score 0):

Christian helped find a way by using actionparam. i have put code in following

```
<a4j:commandButton value="delete" >
<a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="reviewArea">
    <a4j:actionparam name="setViewMode" assignTo="#{backingBean.selectTmpId}" value="#{item.id}" actionListener="#{backingBean.viewMsgContent}" />
</a4j:support>
```